# Struggling with tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am struggling with my first app using the `TabHost' widget in Android.

I have defined my XML layout as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   tools:context=".fragments.ConditionsDialogFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_button"
    android:text="ddddd"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_lbl0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name_banner"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Display Prompts"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/firstDivider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/name_lbl0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="#BFBDBE" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_lbl1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstDivider"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Order Placer :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cond_c01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstDivider"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name_lbl1"
    android:text="XXXX"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_lbl2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name_lbl1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name_lbl1"
    android:text="Specimen Taker :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cond_c02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name_lbl1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name_lbl2"
    android:text="XXXX"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="OK" />

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_lbl1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cond_c02"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout is used within a `DialogFragment` with the following code :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View thisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nlmc_conditions, container, false);

    TextView bannerName = (TextView)thisView.findViewById(R.id.name_banner);
    TextView c01 = (TextView)thisView.findViewById(R.id.cond_c01);
    TextView c02 = (TextView)thisView.findViewById(R.id.cond_c02);

    c01.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHOICEORDERDISPLAY")));
    c02.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHOICETAKERDISPLAY")));

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)thisView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabSpec ts = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        ts.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        ts.setIndicator("Tab one");
        tabHost.addTab(ts);


    bannerName.setText(conditions.Specimen + " specimen preconditions");

    return thisView;
}
```

When it runs the screen is not displayed and the app fails, the log is here :

```
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149): java.lang.NullPointerException
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.<init>(TabHost.java:629)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.<init>(TabHost.java:624)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec.setContent(TabHost.java:473)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at com.apps4care.nlmcbrowser.fragments.ConditionsDialogFragment.onCreateView(ConditionsDialogFragment.java:69)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        03-20 13:35:48.129: E/AndroidRuntime(17149):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        03-20 13:40:48.179: I/Process(17149): Sending signal. PID: 17149 SIG: 9
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of other, I found the issue.

I forgot to add the following, before I used the TabHost class.

```
tabHost.setup();
```